# Removing stopwords from a pandas series based on list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stop-words

I have the following data frame called sentences

```
data = ["Home of the Jacksons"], ["Is it the real thing?"], ["What is it with you?"], [ "Tomatoes are the best"] [ "I think it's best to path ways now"]


sentences = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['sentence'])
```

And a dataframe called stopwords:

```
data = [["the"], ["it"], ["best"], [ "is"]]

stopwords = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['word'])
```

I want to remove all stopwords from sentences["sentence"]. I tried the code below but it does not work. I think there is an issue with my if statement. Can anyone help?

```
Def remove_stopwords(input_string, stopwords_list): 
    stopwords_list = list(stopwords_list)
    my_string_split = input_string.split(' ')
    my_string = []
    for word in my_string_split: 
        if word not in stopwords_list: 
            my_string.append(word)
        my_string = " ".join(my_string)
        return my_string

sentence['cut_string']= sentence.apply(lambda row: remove_stopwords(row['sentence'], stopwords['word']), axis=1)
```

When I apply the function, it just returns the first or first few strings in the sentence but does not cut out stopwords at all. Kinda stuck here

Comment: Please fix syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert stopwords word to list and remove those words from sentences using list comprehension,

```
stopword_list = stopwords['word'].tolist()

sentences['filtered] = sentences['sentence'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([i for i in x.split() if i not in stopword_list]))
```

You get

```
0                 Home of Jacksons
1                   Is real thing?
2                   What with you?
3                     Tomatoes are
4    I think it's to path ways now
```

Or you can wrap the code in a function,

```
def remove_stopwords(input_string, stopwords_list):     
    my_string = []
    for word in input_string.split(): 
        if word not in stopwords_list: 
            my_string.append(word)

    return " ".join(my_string)

stopword_list = stopwords['word'].tolist()
sentences['sentence'].apply(lambda row: remove_stopwords(row, stopword_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many syntax errors in your code above. If you keep the stopwords as a list (or set) rather than DataFrame the following will work -

```
data = ["Home of the Jacksons", "Is it the real thing?", "What is it with you?", "Tomatoes are the best", "I think it's best to path ways now"]
sentences = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['sentence'])

stopwords = ["the", "it", "best", "is"]


sentences.sentence.str.split().apply(lambda x: " ".join([y for y in x if y not in stopwords]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to success is to convert the list of stopwords into a `set()`: sets have O(1) lookup times, while lists' time is O(N).

```
stop_set = set(stopwords.word.tolist())
sentences.sentence.str.split()\
         .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(w for w in x if w not in stop_set))
```